# Boost, C++ how to kill thread opened by another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

so I have some main function. 24 time a second it opens a boost thread `A` with a function. that function takes in a buffer with data. It starts up a boost timer. It opens another thread `B` with a function sending buffer into it. I need thread A to kill thread B if it is executing way 2 long. Of course if thread B has executed in time I do not need to kill it it should kill itself. What boost function can help me to kill created thread (not join - stop/kill or something like that)?

BTW I cannot affect speed of Function I am exequting in thread B thats why I need to be capable of killing it when needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term you are looking for is "cancellation", as in [pthread_cancel(3)](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_cancel.html).  Cancellation is troublesome, because the cancelled thread might not execute C++ destructors or release locks on the way out ... but then again it might; the uncertainty is actually *worse* than a definitive no.

Because of this, boost threads do not support cancellation (see for instance [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039918/boost-thread-cancelling)) but they do support [interruption](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.interruption), which you might be able to bend to fit.  Interruption works by way of a regular C++ exception so it has predictable semantics.

Answer (score 5):

There's no clean way to kill a thread, so if you need to do something like this, your clean choices are to either use a function that includes some cancellation capability, or use a separate process for it, since you *can* kill a process cleanly.

Other than that, my immediate reaction is that instead of "opening" (do you mean creating?) thread A 24 times a second, you'd be better off with thread A reading a buffer, sending it on to thread B, then sleeping until it's ready to read another buffer. Creating and killing threads isn't *terribly* expensive, but doing it at a rate of 24 (or, apparently, 48) a second strikes me as a bit excessive.

Answer (score 2):

please don't kill threads at random unless you completely control their execution (and then just make proper signals for threads to exit gracefully). you never know if other thread is in some critical section of a library you never heard of and then your program will end up stalling on that CS as it was never exited or something like that.