# Terminate boost thread (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, boost

I have one problem, I need to terminate boost thread. And do this from main thread. Using a flag is not suitable. Please help me. I need windows solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "Use the flag is not suitable."?

Comment: Did you try with [thread::interrupt()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.interrupt)?

Comment: Always terminate threads cooperatively. Trying to forcefully abort a thread is dangerous in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, read the answer to [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125666/boost-c-how-to-kill-thread-opened-by-another-thread).
If nevertheless you must terminate thread on Windows, you can do that like this: `TerminateThread(yourThread.native_handle());`